# HtmlAgilityPack scraping - extracting specific nodes from html document

Tags: c#, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Apologies in advance if this has already been answered(if so please point me to right location), I searched here, web, youtube and so on for two days and still haven't founnd an answer.

I would like to extract some data from following url: https://betcity.ru/en/results/sp_fl=a:46;

I am trying to get all event names for the day(1st one is: 
Ho Kwan Kit/Wong Chun Ting — Fan Zhendong/Xu Xin and all others after it). When I inspect that element I can see this part of html:

```
<div class="content-results-data__event"><span>Ho Kwan Kit/Wong Chun Ting — Fan Zhendong/Xu Xin</span></div>
```

I was thinking of getting all div's with class="content-results-data__event" and than get inner text from those div's. Every time I run my code I get zero          results. Why am I not getting any nodes when I can see that div's with such class exist and how can I get all events (if I learn how to do that I could get other info which I need from this site). Here is my code (have to say I am fairly new to this).

```
public partial class Scrapper : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Events = new List<string>();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = NewMethod(web);
        var Nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath: "//div[@class='content - results - data__event'']").ToList();

        foreach (var item in Nodes)
        {
            Events.Add(item.InnerText);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = Events;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }

    private static HtmlDocument NewMethod(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web)
    {
        return web.Load("https://betcity.ru/en/results/sp_fl=a:46;");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what data you are trying to scrape. Preferably the entire xpath. Second it is not easy to scrape a website that has it content updated via script. I prefer using Selenium in such cases.
Third - whatever method you use to scrape the data it is going to be slow especially if you plan to do calculation on the odds that are prone to changing. I recommend you find the API if the site even provides it.

Comment: I was trying to get list of all matches for the day. First one is the one I wrote in,2nd one is Gerassimenko Kirill — Achanta Sharath Kamal and so on. My final goal was to create personal data base with all events, scores and so on. If there will be any calculation performed data would be pulled from sql DB. It looks like I bite more than I can chew at the moment taking in account my coding skills. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This is most likely outside most peoples scope of skills. Firstly - using Charles or Fiddler yields no data presented on the page. You can see the web requests and the resulted pages. However the data on the page is updated through very dense javascripts files. I recommend you use Selenium with a headless driver like Selenium to get the HTML on the page. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47365654/1940851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to get the HTML for one day of matches using Selenium. Rest is HtmlAgilityPack. The site uses self signed certificates so I had to configure the driver to accept self signed certificates. Have fun.

```
        var ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        ffOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
        ffOptions.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Default;
        ffOptions.Profile = new FirefoxProfile { AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true };
        var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
       var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, ffOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

        string url = "https://betcity.ru/en/results/date=2017-11-19;"; //remember to update the date accordingly.

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Write(driver.PageSource);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did made some progress with your help. Will see will I be able to see it to the end. Much appreciated.