# How to scrape the column data (Jquery Datatables) which is invisible in the website using c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, datatables, html-agility-pack

I need to scrape the data of a Jquery data table on the website.

Currently, I'm using Html Agility Pack for scraping the column data.I'm able to scrape all the columns which are visible but I'm unable to scrape few columns that are invisible since User needs to check some checkboxes so that the column elements will be visible in the website.

Comment: You won't get any answers here unless you show us the code you have working now and point out what's not working. That's how this we site works. No one is going to be able to guess a solution to your problem from your description

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290423/how-can-i-scrape-data-from-a-webpage-after-searching-desired-data-using-html-agi?rq=1

Comment: You cant. When you are hiding columns in jQuery DataTables, they are completely removed from the DOM.